# What happens to our rep-earned privileges after the Private Beta?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

The current FAQ says:

> (note that reputation requirements have been relaxed to very low levels for the brief duration of the private beta only)

So apparently when the site enters public beta in a few days, the rep necessary to, for instance, show total up and down vote counts, will go from the current level of 100, to 750, as on other public beta sites.

What does this mean for those of us who have earned privilege during private beta?  Will we be grand-fathered in with our privileges, or will we lose a bunch that we have to re-earn?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will lose any special privileges you had during private beta if you do not have enough reputation to sustain them when the requirements change. Work hard during the private beta so that you don't loose them! This is a jump-start phase ... time to get your engine running.

This is covered on the [main meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) in quite a few places.

See also: [Can we grandfather in rep abilities as sites leave beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67054/can-we-grandfather-in-rep-abilities-as-sites-leave-beta)

Answer (score 2):

You may lose privileges.  And not just from (private) beta to beta or launch, but during normal operation too: privileges always depend on the rep you have *right now*.  As you may lose rep, you may lose privileges too.  Unlike badges, which, once awarded, you get to keep, privileges are fully dynamic.